# Authorization Code Flow API Вконтакте

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, express

Использую метод авторизации Authorization Code Flow в API Вконтакте. Безопасно ли использовать полученный токен для общения между моим сервером и клиентом вместо сессии? Т.е мой сервер получает токен от вк, затем я его использую для общения между клиентом и своим сервером передавая его в куках клиент/сервер. В качестве сервера использую node/express.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше было бы установить защищённое общение. Передавать ключ с паролем, а клиент просто дешифрует.